# ElasticSearch GET /_cat/indices returns 400 illegal_argument_exception error

Tags: elasticsearch, cat, indices

I have strange problem with _cat/indices on a client deployment:
The response is:
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Values less than -1 bytes are not supported: -9223372036854768225b".
Can you please help me in resolving this?

Comment: Can you please add more details like how you are calling this API ? is it from postman or kibana or curl ? which method you are using GET or POST ? etc..

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? If yes, can you share how?